# test for the convergence of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Test the convergence of summation $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$$ where $$x_{2n-1}=\frac{n}{n+1}\\ x_{2n}=-\frac{n}{n+1}$$
That is the series $$\frac 1 2-\frac 12+\frac 23-\frac 23 +-\cdots$$

what I did was let Sn be the partial sums of the series.Then

$$S_n=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{when } n \text{ is even} \\ 
         \frac{n}{n+1} &\text{when } n \text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$

thus $$\lim\limits_{ n\to \infty}  S_n= \begin{cases} 0 & \text{when } n \text{ is even}\\ 
        1 &  \text{when } n \text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$

Thus $\lim\limits_{ n\to \infty}  S_n$ doesn't converge to a particular value. Hence  $\lim\limits_{ n\to \infty}  S_n$ doesn't exist. Therefore the series diverge.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with MathJax, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: Your formula for $S_n$ when $n$ is odd is wrong. The formula for $S_{2n-1} =\frac{n}{n+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but I would say it differently. What you mean is that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{2n}=0$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{2n+1}=1$$

Note that if we "introduced parenthesis", and set $$a_n=x_{2n-1}+x_{2n}$$ the series $$\sum a_n$$ would converge to $0$.

Comment: What you mean by introduced paranthesis is after a rearrangement of the series right?I want to know if my statement "Thus limn→∞Sn doesn't converge to a particular value. Hence limn→∞Sn doesn't exist. Therefore the series diverge." is correct.

Answer (score 2):

A much easier way, imo, to show the series doesn't converge:

$$|x_n|=\frac n{n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\neq 0$$

and thus the series $\,\sum x_n\,$ cannot converge.

Comment: Is it okay to consider only limit of n/n+1.Because clearly this is not $a_n$ of the series.This was done by divergence test right? (since limit of $a_n$ is not 0 the series diverge).Also if we have a series which is made up of two series where one converge and the other diverge, does the complete series diverge

Comment: Yes, it is o.k. since even if it is only a subsequence the fact that its limit isn't zero shows that the general term sequence doesn't converge to zero.

Comment: This is a **series** not a sequence.For a sequence I know that every subsequence should converge.But does the same thing apply for a series?

Comment: A series is just a sequence of partial sums.

Comment: No Paul: a series is **not** a sequence, neither of partial sums or anything else. In order to find out whether a series converges or not then we take its partial sums' sequence, but those are two rather different things.